# Updating calendar

Tags: java, oop, calendar

I'm reasonably new to programming and I'm currently learning the whole object oriented aspect of it. I'm clueless though on how to update my calendar object. Not quite sure what's needed in my update method to update the calendar. Below are the two classes I'm using.

```
public class Time {
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int second;
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    public Time(){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        this.hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        this.minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        this.second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    }
    public int getHour(){
        return this.hour;
    }
    public int getMinute(){
        return this.minute;
    }
    public int getSecond(){
        return this.second;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return this.hour + ":" + this.minute + ":" + this.second;
    }
    public void update(){
        cal.setTime(new Date());    
    }
}
```

And here's my main class:

```
public class Exercise2b {
    public void demo() {
        String message1, message2;
        int hour, minute, second;
        Time dt = new Time();
        hour = dt.getHour();
        minute = dt.getMinute();
        second = dt.getSecond();
        message1 = "Klockan är " + minute + " minuter över " + hour + " (+" + second + " sekunder)";
        message2 = dt.toString();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message1);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message2);
        dt.update();
        message2 = dt.toString();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Exercise2b prog = new Exercise2b();
        prog.demo();    
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried anything to update the calendar? searched for examples online?

Comment: If you're not forced to use `Calendar`, use the new `java.time` API instead.

Answer (score 1):

In the update function you are only updating the instance of the cal. You have to update the hour min and second variables too. You can do it like this.

```
public void update(){
    cal.setTime(new Date());  
    this.hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    this.minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    this.second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
}
```

To get the difference in time you can use **Thread.Sleep()**

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Exercise2b {
public void demo() {
    String message1, message2;
    int hour, minute, second;
    Time dt = new Time();
    hour = dt.getHour();
    minute = dt.getMinute();
    second = dt.getSecond();
    message1 = "Klockan är" +minute+"minuter över"+hour+"(+"+second+"sekunder)";
    message2 = dt.toString();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message1);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message2);

    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception Occured");
    }

    dt.update();

    message2 = dt.toString();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message2);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {  
    Exercise2b prog = new Exercise2b();
    prog.demo();    
    }
}
```

Comment: @Bengan if the answer helps feel free to mark that as right